# Connect via GPRS to SQL Instance without public IP

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, vpn, gprs

We have the following set up:

- Windows Mobile Device with GPRS connection
- Windows Server PC with SQL Server 2012
- VPN Network where both devices contained (the cell carrier routes certain IPs inside VPN)

**Status:**

With the above set up I can ping directly from the mobile device to Windows server internal IP via GPRS.

**Question:**

- Can I create connection to SQL server from my Mobile using the server's internal IP?

My con string is:

```
"Data Source =xxxxxxxx,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;User id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Connect Timeout=15"
```

**EDIT:**

More Questions:

- How can I implement it if yes
- What are the pros and cons in accordance to David's comment

Comment: You can but I would strongly advise against it. Much better to have a middle tier service that interfaces between the mobile device and the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a VPN and can ping the internal server then you *can* connect directly to SQL Server using the normal data access libraries available in the .Net Framework. Having said that, I would strongly advise against it. It's much preferable to have a middle tier service that interfaces between the mobile device and the database. Here are some reasons (off the top of my head) why this is better:

- Mobile connections are inherently unstable and SQL connections are not great at handling that.
- Having a service means you don't even need a VPN as it can be public facing (with relevant security of course).
- If in future you decide to move form SQL Server to DocumentDB/Azure/carrier pigeon, then you need to update every single mobile device to cope with the change. If you have an intermediate server, you can just update that.
- If database schema changes, you may break all of your client applications in one go.
- Your middle tier can do other useful things like caching, logging etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I can't connect using the above con string. I don't know if there is sth more I need to specify on it.

Comment: It could be firewall or SQL not listening on the correct IP addresses?